# How to Pass Parameter to bcp command line in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I have gone through many posts, but none seem to work, I keep getting an error.

I first tried this :

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell'bcp ClientDB.dbo.SparePartsPriceList_Temp_Export out ' + @OutPutFolder + '\' + @DealerType +'-XP006.txt  -c -T -S DEV-PC\SQLEXPRESS'
```

Got getting an error on the first ' + ' : `Incorrect syntax near '+'`

I then tried this:

```
SET @SQLExport = 'bcp ClientDB.dbo.SparePartsPriceList_Temp_Export out ''' + @OutPutFolder + '''\''' + @DealerType +'''-XP006.txt  -c -T -S DEV-PC\SQLEXPRESS'

exec master..xp_cmdshell @SQLExport
```

But when I execute the Stored Procedure, I get the following error :`Procedure expects parameter 'command_string' of type 'varchar'.`

I cant imagine this being so difficult, but I am most probably missing something small.

Please can someone tell me what I am missing ? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass an expression, to `xp_cmdshell`. You'll need to use dynamic SQL. This is untested, however...:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'EXEC master..xp_cmdshell ''bcp ClientDB.dbo.SparePartsPriceList_Temp_Export out ' + QUOTENAME(@OutPutFolder + '\' + @DealerType +'-XP006.txt','"') + N' -c -T -S DEV-PC\SQLEXPRESS''';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem! Which I got from this post: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1071530/xpcmdshell--Procedure-expects-parameter-commandstring-of-type-varchar

The reason is because you can't use varchar(max) with xp_cmdshell. Once I changed MAX to 4000, it worked....